# 'y' was not declared in this scope,

Tags: c++, compilation

I had a lot of problems with this project, I figured out a lot. but this one I can't

Here I have some calculations, and then I need this "y" variable to pass to next .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int Ing(int number, float y)
{
y = 0;
float Lngth = 0;
for(; number != 0; number /= 10, Lngth++);
float n = nearbyint(sqrt(Lngth));
y = Lngth * pow(10, n);
return  (y);
}
```

here is the next .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "InitialGuess.h"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int SquareRoot(int number, int th)
{
float iGuess = Ing(y);
float x = iGuess;
 for (int k=1; k< th; ++k)
    {
        x = (x + (number / x ))/2; 
} 
cout<<x;    
return (x);
}
```

But on compilation It gives me error that "y" was not declared in this scope.
Where I've made a mistake?

Thank you

Comment: Change it to `int y = 0;`

Comment: You need to learn about C++ Scopes to understand that the error message couldn't be more clear in telling you how to fix the problem: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: If I change it to int y = 0, it's gonna shadow parametr

Comment: Maybe you don't understand that the function SquareRoot is a different scope from the function Ing.  Just because you provided the variable in one doesn't provide it in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = 0;
```

should be

```
int y = 0;
```

because `y` has not yet be declared at this point and you are defining a variable.

Comment: I need "y" from first function in second. and in first function I have

    int Ing(int number, float y)

Comment: Make the y variable a global variable.

Comment: is there any way where I can avoid making "y" global variable?

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
float iGuess = Ing(y);
```

you don't have y declared, which causes the error. What value do you want to pass to Ing()?

You've got 2 parameters defined for Ing(int, float) but only calling it with one.

Comment: I want get value of Ing(y)

Comment: so in the first function, after calculations i'm getting "y".
then I need this "y" in the second function. It's just a single number.